# Out of bound exception, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:257 java

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

everyone. I have a question regarding ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

I know that ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error usually comes from the wrong space allocation and I searched a dozens of questions from stackoverflow about ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException but haven't found the solution for mine.

Following is my code.

```
public void doKDE2D2()
{
    double d = 0;
    double r = 0;
    double[][] cor = new double[n + 1][n + 1];

    gx = makeSequence( lims[0], lims[1], n + 1 );
    gy = makeSequence( lims[2], lims[3], n + 1 );
    z = new double[n][n];

    for ( int NormalizedValueXCnt = 0; NormalizedValueXCnt < x.length; NormalizedValueXCnt++ )
    {
        int startBlockX = blockSequence( x[NormalizedValueXCnt] )[0];
        int endBlockX = blockSequence( x[NormalizedValueXCnt] )[1];
        int startBlockY = blockSequence( y[NormalizedValueXCnt] )[0];
        int endBlockY = blockSequence( y[NormalizedValueXCnt] )[1];

        for ( int CntGridBlockX = startBlockX; CntGridBlockX < endBlockX; CntGridBlockX++ )
        {

            for ( int CntGridBlockY = startBlockY; CntGridBlockY < endBlockY; CntGridBlockY++ )
            {
                double dx = x[NormalizedValueXCnt] - gx[CntGridBlockX];
                double dy = y[NormalizedValueXCnt] - gy[CntGridBlockY];

                r = Math.sqrt( ( dx * dx ) - ( dy * dy ) );

                if ( r < h )
                {
                    d = ( r / h );
                    cor[CntGridBlockX][CntGridBlockY] += kCalculation( d ) * c[NormalizedValueXCnt];

                }
                else
                {

                   // cor[lengthOfGridBlockX][lengthOfGridBlockY] += 0;

                }

            }
        }
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            z[i][j] = ( cor[i][j] + cor[i][j + 1] + cor[i + 1][j] + cor[i + 1][j + 1] ) / 4;
        }
    }

}


public double[] makeSequence( double start, double end, int length )
{
    double[] seq = new double[length];
    double by = ( end - start ) / ( length - 1 );
    double value = start;
    for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++, value += by )
    {
        seq[i] = value;
    }
    return seq;
}

private void setupLims(double lengthOfGraph )
{
    lims = new double[4];
    lims[0] = -1 * (lengthOfGraph/2);
    lims[1] = (lengthOfGraph/2);
    lims[2] = -1 * (lengthOfGraph/2);
    lims[3] = (lengthOfGraph/2);

}
```

Whenever I put under 3 for the variable lengthOfGraph of setupLims method, 256 for the variable length of makeSequence method, I get the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:257 on the line

```
  double dx = x[NormalizedValueXCnt] - gx[CntGridBlockX];
```

of doKDE2D2 Method.
 Does anybody have an idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome. I can suggest some debug output statements just before the offending statement to help you see why it is happening.

Comment: Where are you declaring the array 'x'?

Comment: @MrPublic it is a global variable defined above(not in the code that I uploaded)